# interpreting chi square value for validating random numbers

Tags: chi-squared-test, randomness

I am trying to use the chi-square test for identifying random data. I have 256 categories, i.e. 255 degrees of freedom and count the occurrence of byte-values (0-255). As suggested by Knuth, the observed sequence of bytes is random, if the chi-square value is between the chi-square-values of p=5% and p=95% (I read these value from the table). the test works but I am trying to understand why :)

I have no idea about statistics, this is my problem right now. I am trying to understand what the p-value actually is and its relation to alpha. It is said that the null-hypothesis is rejected if the computed chi-statistic is above the chi-square value depending on alpha.

Knuth has a table where all chi-square-values are listed depending on the p-value. can anybody explain to me why? Why does he say that the calculated chi-square-statistic MUST be between p=5% and p=95% if data is random?

Thank you guys very much for any answer!

Comment: Which of Knuth's works are you quoting specifically?

Comment: Donald E. Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming, Seminumerical Algorithms

Comment: In my copy (1998, Addison-Wesley) Knuth discusses the chi-squared test in section 3.3.1.  *Nowhere* does he insist the p-value must lie between 5% and 95%.  I recommend you read that section with more care.

Comment: he doesnt say explecitely between 5% and 95%, but please check the example on p.42. In this example for the chi-statistic V1 is too high and V2 is too low.

Comment: this guy here is referring to Knuth on p. 8 and describes what i said. [http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/students/reu/pRNGs.pdf](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/students/reu/pRNGs.pdf)

Comment: The exposition is full of cautions: you need to read the text, not just focus on one example.  For instance: "Remember, however, that even *good* dice would give such a high value of $V$ about one time in a hundred, so a cautious person would repeat the experiment to see if the high value of $V$ is repeated."  Towards the end of the section he suggests rejecting the null hypothesis of randomness whenever the p-value is more extreme than $1$% or $99$%, *in at least two out of three repetitions of the experiment.* This is an effective p-value of $4(.02)^3 =.000032$, which is highly convincing.

Comment: Your reference mentions Knuth's exhortation to repeat the experiment twice.  It also characterizes this rule as "arbitrary" and says will be "improved on" later.  Once again, I recommend you read the *entire* text rather than focusing on one mechanical part of the procedure it describes.

Comment: ok thank you so far, i will do that. only one more thing: everywhere i see the chi-square table according to alpha, knuth has the table according to the p-value. is it possible for you to explain the relation in easy words? or better said: why i need the p-value if the alpha is everything for performing this test? thank you very much!

Comment: The NIST [http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips1401.htm#sec4.11](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips1401.htm#sec4.11) describes in some tests it uses for identifying randomness the chi-square-test, too. As you can see e.g. in definition of the poker test, they write "The test is passed if 1.03 < X < 57.4". Is there any reason why they check for both sides?!

Comment: Knuth discusses this: you worry about the distribution being uneven (detected by a large chi-squared value) and about being *too* even (which is a subtle but potentially important departure from randomness): that's detected by a chi-squared value which is too small.

Comment: so I couldn't have been wrong because this is what i meant from the beginning :) sorry for my expression. but does he have a rule when the chi-squared value is too small?

Comment: @tom given the long discussion with whuber I am not sure whether he has cleared up all of what was confusing you.  I think he did a good job of cautioning you how to interpret what Knuth says in his book. I got the impression that you were confusing p-values with significance levels. Significance levels are used to find percentage points from the null distribution (in this case the chi square where you would choose to reject the null hypothesis (in this case near uniformity).  The p-value on the other hand is based on the calculated value of the test statistic based on the data.

Comment: The p-value tells you the probability of observing a value as extreme as what you got when the null hypothesis is true.  This measn that if your significance level is say 0.05 and your p-vlaue is less than 0.05 you would reject the null hypothesis. It also means that the observed value is larger in absolute value than the critical value from the chi square table.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you very much... this was probably my mistake. But one more thing is confusing me. Why does the NIST say "The test is passed if 1.03 < X < 57.4" and not just below 57.4? So there must be one lower and one upper limit.